# Multi-statement in a line

Tags: bison, yacc

What's wrong with my code?
- it compiles correctly the 'while' structure
- it compiles correctly the colon separeted statements
- but reports syntax error if colon separeted statements are in a 'while' structure. Here it is:

```
0x363> while (a>b) { a=3 }
0x36e > a=3 : b=2
0x376 > while (a>b) { a=3 : b=2 }
syntax error
```

I suppose my stmt_list is wrong - but what's the correct solution?

> Note: I do not use any special terminal character like ';'

```
stmt:
    .....
    | WHILE '(' expr ')' stmt_list  { $$ = opr(WHILE, 2, $3, $5); }
    .....


stmt_list:
    stmt                { $$ = $1; }
    | stmt ':' stmt         { $$ = opr(':', 2, $1, $3); }
    | '{' stmt_list '}'     { $$ = $2; }
    ;
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you deliberately trying to restrict statement lists to no more than two statements? That seems odd to me.

Also, your `while` statement is ambiguous, since a stmt_list could be `a=3 : b=2` (without the `{}`). Consequently, the following is legal but can be parsed two ways:

```
while (a>b) while (c>d) a=b : c=d
```

What I would have expected would be:

```
stmt:
   ...
   | while '(' expr ')' stmt  /* NOT stmt_list */
   ...
   | '{' stmt_list '}'
   ;

stmt_list:
   stmt
   | stmt_list ':' stmt
   ;
```

None of that explains where your syntax error is coming from, though. I suspect the answer has to do with how you compose statements into a program, since your example demonstrates that a program is not a stmt_list (unless you have some hack to insert colons at line ends).

Comment: No, I don't want to restrict statement list to two items. I have tried as suggested, I copy-paste here:   | WHILE '(' expr ')' stmt       { $$ = opr(WHILE, 2, $3, $5); }
 | '{' stmt_list '}'         { $$ = $2; }
 | error {
  yyerror((char *)yytext);
  $$ = NULL;
  errorflag=1;
  }
 ;

stmt_list:
 stmt            { $$ = $1; }
 | stmt_list ':' stmt        { $$ = opr(':', 2, $1, $3); }
 ;

Comment: @user2469202: yes, I didn't think the fix to stmt_list would fix the syntax error problem. See the last paragraph of my answer.